# how to automatically resize d3.js graph to include axis

Tags: d3.js, dynamic, width, bar-chart, axis

I have a bit of a problem building a bar chart. I'm learning d3.js for the first time and being someone who always worked with PHP/MySQL, I haven't had to learn javascript. As a result, I'm struggling a bit.

My question is more conceptual in nature. If, let's say in a bar chart, the Y axis is contained in a g element and the bars are contained in another one, how can I ensure that my axis takes a dyanmic width based on the data presented?

**I managed to generate a bar chart and it works great, but the padding is a fixed number (let's say 50px). it works great now, because my numbers go from 0 to 50, so everything fits. What happens if I get trillions instead? The width of the axis will change, yet my padding remains 50px, which means it will clip my content.**

What is the "convention" when it comes to this? Any tricks?

Thanks

Comment: You can set padding = 0.1*width for example

Comment: thanks, but that's still a fixed value. it will always to compute basedon the width, not taking into account the width of the text of my labels. is there a way to get the width of the current element being generated? then I could use the width of the g containing the axis and offset by that.

Comment: this might help https://bl.ocks.org/curran/3a68b0c81991e2e94b19

Comment: If you are prepared to do some reading, look up the "viewBox" attribute. Basically it defines the coordinate system within the SVG, and ALL numbers inside the SVG relate to the viewBox coordinates. So you can specify 50px padding, and if the svg happens to be trillions of pixels wide, the padding will scale.

Comment: ok, it seems I need to start drawing as it's not clear what I'm after. I'm not talking about scaling the graph, that's fine. I'm saying that the axis' width will change based on the labels. if my axis goes from 1 to 9, the width will be based on one character. however, change the values to 100000000 and clearly I will need more space to accommodate the wider text. this is something I'm looking to do dynamically, as I don't know what data will be represented in the graph.

Comment: Ah, i get it. You should consider using SI prefixes found in `d3.format`. No one wants to read `1,000,000,000`, but prefixed numbers such as `1T`, `1.5B`, `100M` are a lot easier to read. It also solves your space problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One trick you might use here is what I like to call the "double-render".  You essentially draw the axis first (before the rest of the plot) and get the width of the greatest tick label.  The, You can draw the plot conventionally with that value as the margin.  This trick is especially useful for string "category" labels, but will work for numbers as well.

Here's a commented example.  Run it multiple times to see how it refits the axis:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .bar {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
  .bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
  }
  
  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//chancejs.com/chance.min.js"></script>
<script>


  // set up some random data
  // pick a random max value to render on the yaxis
  var maxVal = chance.integer({
      min: 1,
      max: chance.pickone([1e1, 1e5, 1e10])
    }),
    // generate some fake data
    data = [{
      x: chance.word(),
      y: chance.floating({
        min: 0,
        max: maxVal
      })
    }, {
      x: chance.word(),
      y: chance.floating({
        min: 0,
        max: maxVal
      })
    }, {
      x: chance.word(),
      y: chance.floating({
        min: 0,
        max: maxVal
      })
    }, {
      x: chance.word(),
      y: chance.floating({
        min: 0,
        max: maxVal
      })
    }];

  // create svg and set up a y scale, the height value doesn't matter
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([100, 0]);

  // set domain
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })]);

  // draw fake axis
  var yAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // determine max width of text label
  var mW = 0;
  yAxis.selectAll(".tick>text").each(function(d) {
    var w = this.getBBox().width;
    if (w > mW) mW = w;
  });

  // remove fake yaxis
  yAxis.remove();

  // draw plot normally
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: mW + 10 // max with + padding fudge
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // reset to actual height
  y.range([height, 0]);

  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.y);
    });
</script>
```